# how can i pass table values to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried to use this code to pass a table the values(it has int and strings) of one page to another. When a button is clicked ,it should go to the other page and show the table values. someone could help me?

This is the code in the first page that should transform the table in json and post :

```
$("#pdfrequest").click(function() {
   var TableData;
   TableData = storeTblValues();
   TableData = $.JSON.stringify(TableData);

   function storeTblValues() {
     var TableData = new Array();

     $('#listasBody tr').each(function(row, tr) {
       TableData[row] = {
         "numItem": $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(), //numero do item
         "codItem": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(), //codigo do item
         "quantidadeprod": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(), //nquantidade do produto
         "descr": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(), //descricap
         "precprod": $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(), // preco unitario
         "prectot": $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text() //preco tota
       }

     });
     TableData.shift(); // retirar a primeira row por ser table header
     return TableData;
   }

   var TableData;
   TableData = JSON.stringify(TableData);

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "pdfForm.php",
     data: TableData,
     success: function(msg) {

     }
   });

 });
```

and in the socond page i tried using this to show something from the table:

```
?php
      $tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['TableData']);
      $tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
      echo $tableData[1]['numItem'];
?>
```

But there was errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: pTableData in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 514
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: json_decode in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 515
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 515

Comment: you have error in your code "$json_decode" change to "json_decode"

Comment: thanks,but now it says  Undefined variable: Tabledata in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 515

Comment: var TableData; is defined multiple times

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: Undefined index: pTableData in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 514

Try changing:

```
data: "pTableData=" + TableData,
```

&

```
$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
```

To:

```
data: TableData,
```

&

```
$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['TableData']);
```

EDIT: Also, you could & should check the array/object you create:

```
console.log(TableData);
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: json_decode in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 515

`json_decode()` is a function, not a variable, remove the `$`.

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 515

Should be fixed if you applied the changes above.

Comment: thanks i made the changes but appeared a different error:Notice: Undefined index:TableData in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\pdfForm.php on line 514

Comment: Use `console.log(TableData);` to check your array, it's probably empty.

Comment: its empty,and the error still cotinues to appear, thank for de advice about the console.log

Comment: should i use other id than the table id?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you should make sure your object/array actually contains data before sending it to a PHP file. If you don't know how to do that, you should submit another question. Also it would be nice if you accept my answer as this solved the current problem. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

//Initializing variable

```
$value1 = "";
```

//Initialization value; Examples "" When you want to append , 0  When you want to add numbers

//isset

```
$value1 = isset($_POST['value1'])  ? $_POST['value1'] : '';
```

//empty

```
$value1 = !empty($_POST['value1']) ? $_POST['value1'] : '';
```